# Mobile srcset inconsistent results

Tags: responsive-images, srcset

Another question on srcset not working but I've waded through the countless questions here and most of them seem to be either 'open your test in private window' or 'srcset doesn't work in that browser' kind of response.

I've checked both the above and still can't get my mobile portrait image to load consistently.

I'm working in FF and if I narrow the window to less than 769px, it displays correctly.  If I use dev tools to emulate mobile it doesn't. Most importantly, if I open the codepen on my mobile in FF - it doesn't display the portrait image either. Similar results on Chrome.

Have I made a silly syntax error?

so here it is:

```html
<img class="" 
     srcset="
        https://via.placeholder.com/780x520/91b9c7?text=Standard+Desktop 780w, 
        https://via.placeholder.com/365x520/c49055/3e7a23&text=Mobile+Portrait 365w,
        https://via.placeholder.com/1560x1040/c791c7/0011ff&text=Retina+Desktop 1560w"
     sizes="
        (max-width: 768px) 365px,
        (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) 365px,
        (min-width: 769px) and (orientation: landscape) 780px,
        (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) 1560px,
        (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (orientation: landscape) 1560px,
        365px"
     alt="alt text here">
```

and here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/chrisby34/pen/gObyQZy

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering my own question but finding a solution by using a picture tag instead.

```html
<picture class="" >
     <source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/780x520/91b9c7?text=Standard+Desktop">
      <source media="(min-width: 769px) and (orientation: landscape)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/365x520/c49055/3e7a23&text=Mobile+Portrait">
      <source media="(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1560x1040/c791c7/0011ff&text=Retina+Desktop">
      <source media="(min-resolution: 2dppx) and (orientation: landscape)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1560x1040/c791c7/0011ff&text=Retina+Desktop">
     <img src="low-res.jpg" alt="alt text here">
 </picture>
```